# better version of this sql?

Tags: sql

I am trying to create some counts in my query and my code recalculates the sums over and over.  is there a better way of writting this?

```
if(
    ( 
       (
         select count(`t2`.`id`) 
         from `qbinvoices` `t2` 
         where  `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber`
            and `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
        ) > 0
    ),
    (
      select count(`t2`.`id`) 
      from `qbinvoices_view` `t2`
      where  `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber`
         and `t2`.`monthStart` > 0
         and `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
    ),
    (
      select count(`t2`.`id`) 
      from `qbestimatesnew_view` `t2` 
      where `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber` 
          and `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
    )
) AS `invoiceItemsCount`
```

I am using this:

```
select count(`t2`.`id`) 
from `qbinvoices` `t2` 
where  `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber`
    and `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
```

inside an `If` statement.  ie: `if(mystatement > 0, mystatement, differentVersionOfMyStatement)`

I am also using this inside a view, so I cannot use variables. Is there any way of writing it without repeating the count three times inside the `If` statement?

Comment: First improvement that comes to my mind is to add carriage returns so that horizontal scrolling is not necessary.

Comment: Which dbms??????  `SQL` is just a common language used by many vendors.

Answer (score 2):

I would express this logic as:

```
(case when exists (select 1
                   from `qbinvoices` `t2` 
                   where  `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber` and
                          `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
                  ) 
     then (select count(`t2`.`id`) 
           from `qbinvoices_view` `t2`
           where  `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber` and
                  `t2`.`monthStart` > 0 and
                  `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
         )
     else (select count(`t2`.`id`) 
           from `qbestimatesnew_view` `t2` 
           where `t2`.`qbAccNumber` = `t1`.`qbAccNumber` and
                 `t2`.`divisionId` = `t1`.`divisionId`
          )
end) AS `invoiceItemsCount`
```

`count()` is an expensive operation for determining if records exist.  `exists` has the advantage of stopping at the first matching records.

The other two counts are from different tables.

Also, I prefer `case` to data-specific syntax such as `if()`.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the code does **not** repeat the same count. Each of the existing counts looks at a different data source (`qbinvoices` vs `qbinvoices_view` vs `qbestimatesnew_view`) with a different possible result, and therefore all must be used in the sql code.

What you might be able to do instead is use `JOIN`s in combination with conditional aggregation to roll them up in a way that is simpler to express in the `SELECT` clause and possibly has a faster execution plan. But we'd need to see the entire SQL query to show you more what that looks like here.